# Alternative form of scalar particle dynamics in the gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I am interested in the dynamics of a single (classical) spin-0 particle in the General Relativistic spacetime of arbitrary signature and dimensionality. In the 1-st order (Palatini) formalism, this can be written as

$$ S[X] = -m \intop_{X} d\tau \sqrt{\eta_{IJ} e_{\mu}^{I} e_{\nu}^{J} \dot{X}^{\mu} \dot{X}^{\nu}}, $$

where $X(\tau)$ is (an arbitrarily parametrized) particle worldline.

However, I have recently seen another action in the literature (e.g. in [this action about 3d Euclidean quantum gravity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0401076.pdf) on page 6):

$$ S[X] = \frac{m}{2} \intop_{X} e^0 = \frac{m}{2} \intop_{X} d\tau \, e_{\mu}^0 \dot{X}^{\mu}. $$

It appears to violate gauge invariance, but as far as I understand, authors are claiming that its fine (not exactly sure why though). (Actually, in the mentioned article a more general form of the action is considered which includes the classical angular momentum $s$, but for now I am only interested in the $s = 0$ case).

Question: from a brief look I can tell that the dynamics given by this action is drastically different from the dynamics given by the geometrical "length of the worldline" action above. Which one is physically more suited to describe interactions of (classical) particles with gravity?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just realized how to answer my own question.

The linear action is just a special case of the "length of the worldline" action in the

$$ e^0 \parallel dt;\quad e^{1,2,3}\perp dt $$

case. So this second action is obtained from the first one *after* gauge-fixing.

The whole point of the paragraph, though, is that introducing particle degrees of freedom is equivalent to loosing gauge invariance along the worldline. So by making this choice of gauge-fixing we introduce just as much information as we would by introducing a dynamical particle trajectory.